# How to read from a database and pass it on to a session

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if anyone could shine a light on how to read from a database and pass it on to a sessions variable. I have tried with a product id and get but it did not work.

I'm looking for the basics on how to approach the issue.

Comment: Can you show us some code you've tried ?

Comment: Please SEARCH for solutions before you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to read from MySQL Database (for example).

First thing to do is reading PHP/MYSQL documentation.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Second thing is to read about PHP Sessions.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

And for example some code:

```
// Connect to MySQL Database and select all records from your_table
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM your_table");
$query->execute();
if($query == TRUE) {
   // query success
}
```

To store information in `$_SESSION` variable you need to:

1. Call `session_start();` before accessing this variable
2. `$_SESSION['your_var'] = 'your_value';`

Comment: @Jenis: thanks for wanting to edit posts here. However, please be aware that double colon `::` is not ever used in English - one is fine. Also, ordered lists do not need to be rendered with code formatting. Block formatting is useful for code and console I/O.